# how to store images to a folder from OV7670 camera in a web server using ESP32

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, web-server, camera, esp8266webserver

I'm a beginner at this, but I need to figure out how to store images in a folder from an OV7670 camera on a web server using ESP32 for a school project. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the ESP32 also a web server, or is the web server somewhere  else? ... please edit your question to clarify

Comment: First, take an image and store it on the ESP32. Second, use the ESP32 to POST the image data to a web site. There are numerous tutorials and examples on both of these subjects.